# How escape string works in ObjectMapper of jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, escaping

I want to generate JSON string from given string but with **single backslash character before single quote character** like this \'. For example I have string "you are the 'great'" and want output like this "you are the \'great\'". I am using **jackson object mapper** class and following is the code:

```
    String str = "you are the 'great'";
    String jsonStr = "";
    System.out.println(str);//Line-1
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try
    {
        jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(str);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(jsonStr);//Line-2
```

So based on that I have performed following testcases:

1. Input string: `"you are the \'great\'"`

   Output of Line-1: `you are the 'great'`

   Output of Line-2: `you are the 'great'`
2. Input string: `"you are the \\'great\\'"`

   Output of Line-1: `you are the \'great\'`

   Output of Line-2: `you are the \\'great\\'`

But I am not able to get the expected output. Please provide some solution.

Note: Here to explain you the problem I have taken string as a input but actually I have some string properties in object and want Json string of that object.

Comment: If you want a backslash in your JSON, then this backslash needs to be escaped with another backslash, otherwise it wouldn't be valid JSON anymore. So what you're actually wanting is invalid JSON, and Jackson won't generate that.

Comment: Thanks for reply @JBNizet  . I want to use generated json string as java script variable value on client side like this **var jsonStr = '<<server generated json string>>'**.

Comment: You don't need to do anything to do that. `"you are the 'great'"` is perfectly valid JavaScript. You don't need to escape the single quotes.

Comment: var emailDeliveryChartJsonData = '{"chart":{"paletteColors":"#f3f3f3,#019ddc","startingAngle":"90","showLabels":"0","showPercentValues":"1","enableSlicing":"0","showValues":"0","theme":"fint","animateClockwise":"1","enableRotation":"0","defaultCenterLabel":"100% delivered","centerLabelFontSize":"14","centerLabelColor":"#019ddc","bgColor":"#FFFFFF","bgAlpha":"100,100","centerLabel":"","decimals":"","pieRadius":"85","centerLabelFont":"**'Roboto', sans-serif, Arial**","doughnutRadius":"30"},"data":[{"label":"","value":"0"},{"label":"","value":"1"}]}'; This is the actual usage of it. @JBNizet

Comment: In above string bold text is giving java script exception because i have wrapped whole string in single quote.

Comment: Well, don't put it into a string. You'll have an object, ready to be used. And if you really need the string, then use JSON.stringify().